# ASP.NET Boolean return null when casted into model?

Tags: asp.net, api, casting, boolean

When casting an object into a model, all booleans are set to false when they're not provided. Usually this is a helpful feature, but when it comes to updating an object using my API- I can't recognize the difference between the user not providing a field, or it just going to false because of the model casting.

Is there any way to tackle it, or should the user just be required to pass on the field when updating a record?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution! When initializing variables, use a ? after the type.
Example:

```
bool? isActive;
```

or in VB

```
Property isActive as Boolean?
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: These are called nullables https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx